# xamarin send object with pushmodalasync

Tags: c#, xamarin

i am currently working on a movie app and i need to be able to send the current movie object to my movieDetailspage. But it creates the moviedetails page before it will set a bindingcontext. Maybe im just doing this the wrong way. But i cant figure out why it will not work. Here is my code

My list of movie objects

```
List<MovieList.Movie> movies = new List<MovieList.Movie>();
```

My switch to moviedetails function

```
 async void goToMovie(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            if(movies == null) {

            }
            else {
                MovieDetails movieDetails = new MovieDetails();

                MovieList.Movie sending = movies[movieIndex];

                movieDetails.ContextBinding = sending;

            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(movieDetails);
            }

        }
```

The recieving moviedetails.cs

```
public MovieDetails ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        MovieList.Movie recievedMovie = new MovieList.Movie();
        this.BindingContext = recievedMovie;
```

}

Its not the whole file, but i hope this will suffice.
I have tried breakpoints and what it looks like is that it creates the moviedetails before setting contextbinding and therefore will recievedMovie always be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the selected item in your constructor

```
MovieList.Movie sending = movies[movieIndex];
MovieDetails movieDetails = new MovieDetails(sending);
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(movieDetails);


public MovieDetails (Movie selected)
{
        InitializeComponent ();

        this.BindingContext = selected;
}
```

Comment: That worked! dont need to do bindingcontext then it seems. Thanks  @Jason